# does Passenger work with rvm ruby1.9.2p136 and rails3.0.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger, rvm

Installed rvm
gem installed passenger
when I try to install `passenger-install-apache2-module` it gives?

```
root@c2h2crawler:~# ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [i686-linux]
root@c2h2crawler:~# passenger-install-apache2-module
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem passenger (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:18:in `<main>'
```

Does passenger support  rvm ruby1.9.2p136 and rails3.0.3?

Comment: Are you sure that when you did the "gem install passenger" you were using the same gemset that when you did passenger-install-apache2-module? check that you did: gem list | grep passenger

Comment: they are good, have you tried to make passenger3 work on ruby1.9.2 with apache?

Comment: Yep, I've one application running with that configuration... which is the result of the command: gem list | grep passenger (assuming that you are inside the project's path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, my problem is RVM is not system-wide installed, its kinda of hacked by fixing path by myself.